# Consequences of removing a partnership in sync center?

Tags: windows, networking, sync

Hi I have a windows 7 PC on our network, I don't think we need to have a sync partnership on it and want to disable it. If I disable it does anything get deleted or lost? or does it simply stop syncing? are there any other consequences of disabling a sync partnership?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Microsoft](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/sync-center-frequently-asked-questions), you cannot disable or turn off a sync partnership. You will have to delete the partnership to stop the sync process.

They also state this regarding data loss:

> Deleting a sync partnership rarely deletes any files or other
>   information. It only ends the sync partnership. If you delete a sync
>   partnership, it should warn you first before it deletes files or other
>   information.

To end a sync partnership:

1. Open Sync Center by clicking the Start button, clicking All Programs, clicking Accessories, and then clicking Sync Center.
2. Right-click the sync partnership that you want to end, and then
   click Delete.